# I need help in this integral

Tags: integration

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2}\sec{h^2}(x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{H_n(x\sqrt\alpha)}{\sqrt{2^n n!}}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{H_m(x\sqrt\alpha)}{\sqrt{2^m m!}}dx \vert$$

$H$ is the Hermite polynomial.

$\alpha$ is a positive quantity.

As you know, because of the following relation:
$$H_n(-x)=(-1)^nH_n(x)$$
this integral is nonzero if both $m$ and $n$ be positive or negative. Please consider the positive case.

Comment: Can we see your attempt? Or at least how you thought this might be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

By starting with the integral
\begin{align}
I_{n}^{m} = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{- \alpha t^{2}} \ sech^{2}(t) \ H_{n}(\sqrt{\alpha} t) H_{m}(\sqrt{\alpha} t) \ dt 
\end{align}
and the generating function it is seen that
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} I_{n}^{m} \frac{ x^{n} y^{m} }{n! m!} &= \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{- (\alpha + 2) t^{2}} \ e^{2 \sqrt{\alpha} (x+y) t} sech^{2}(t) \ dt \\
&= e^{\alpha (x+y)^{2}/(\alpha +2)} \ \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{-(\sqrt{\alpha+2}t - p)^{2}} sech^{2}(t) \ dt, 
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
p = \sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+2}} (x+y).
\end{align}
Complete the integral and then evaluate the result to obtain $I_{n}^{m}$.